# Need help understanding the math behind a CVAE

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I am trying to use the following [link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r2/tutorials/generative/cvae.ipynb) to understand how a CVAE works. Although i can see how this works for something like a 28x28x1 input image, I'm not sure how to modify this to work for something like an input image of size 64x64x3.

I have tried looking at other sources for information, but all of them use the MNIST dataset used in the example above. None of them really explain why they chose the numbers for filters, kernels, or strides. I need help understanding this and how to modify the network to work for a 64x64x3.

Comment: Filter sizes and strides etc is addressed in the answer below. The `Conv2D` layer is already designed for convolutions of 2D images over multiple colour channels, as you require in the second question. The only changes you need to make is to ensure the input layers have your correct required dimensions

Answer (score 0):

> None of them really explain why they chose the numbers for filters,
>   kernels, or strides.

I'm new to CNNs too, but from what I understand it's really more about experimentation, there is not an exact formula that would give you the amount of filters you have to use or the correct size, it depends on your problem, if you are trying to recognize an object and the object has small features that would make it "recognizable" to the network, then using a filter of small size may be best, but if you think that the features that allow the network to recognize the object are "bigger", then using filters of bigger size may be best, but again from what I've learned, these are just tips, you may have a CNN that has a completely different configuration.